# Passing broadcast to fragment on OnReceive

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-webview, android-broadcast

on my android app, there are 3 fragments each with 3 webviews and 3 edittexts,i have registered a broadcast receiver so that my webviews get populated on its OnReceive() method.i wish to update all 3 fragments with the same contents ie incoming SMS.but my app crashes each time.have a check on my code.

my main activity...

```
    public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity
    implements NavigationDrawerCallbacks {
    IntentFilter intentFilter;
     private BroadcastReceiver intentReciever = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context,Intent intent ) {
        WebView wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        WebView wv2 = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView2);
        WebView wv3 = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView3);
        final String mimeType = "text/html";
        final String encoding = "UTF-8";
        String html = intent.getExtras().getString("sms");
        wv.loadData(html, mimeType, encoding); //no issue if i use only this
        wv2.loadData(html, mimeType, encoding); //app crashes here
        wv3.loadData(html, mimeType, encoding);  //app crashes here
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"All Fragments Updated",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 }
};
```

theres no problem in displaying if i use only one webview, but i need to get all the webviews updated on Onrecieve()...

Comment: My guess wv2 and wv3 are null, check your layout.

Comment: is there any workaround for my implemnetation?..i need every fragment to be uodated with same content

Comment: Check  if indeed in your layout in every fragment you have 3 webviews with ids webView, webView2 and webView3, If not then you are getting your crash

Comment: im sure everything regrading ids are proper...,is there any other methods so that i can update all webviews at once with same data..?

Comment: Post your logcat with crash

Comment: im using genymotion as testdevice,the crash comes into picture on broadcast OnReceive...is there any way to simulate SMS receive event in genymotion..?right now for this purpose i test it on real device

Comment: Get familiar with logcat then post your logcat log.